# Fix Use of undefined constant” notices using a regex?

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a `regex` expression that can fix the undefined constant notices I am getting below is an example of what I want to achieve.

```
if(!function_exists(foo)) {
    function foo() {

    }
}
if(!function_exists(foo2)) {
    function foo2(){

    }
}
```

Using a Regex expression i want it to look like

```
if(!function_exists('foo')){
    function foo() {

    }
}
if(!function_exists('foo2')) {
    function foo2() {

    }
}
```

Comment: If you have access to the source code then change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find `(?<=function_exists\()\w+`

And replace `'$&'`

It will work..

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help, it all seems to be working except the '$&' after running the code i am getting this: `if(!function_exists('$&')) { function foo() { } } if(!function_exists('$&')) { function foo2() { } }`

Comment: how about `(?<=function_exists\()(\w+)` and `'$1'`